# Paint my collection of geometry feature?

Tags: java, swing, paint, computational-geometry, jviewport

hello am trying to paint my feature ( collection of geometry with a specific color ) but i get this error:
it's a problem with the arraylist to be casted but i don't how to fix it
PLZ help me
Thanks in advance

> ```
> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
> ```
>
> java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to
>   com.vividsolutions.jts.geom.GeometryCollection at
>   com.vividsolutions.jump.workbench.ui.plugin.specific.SearchPropertiesPlugin$3.actionPerformed(SearchPropertiesPlugin.java:205)
>   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:1995)
>   at
>   javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2318)
>   at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:387)
>   at
>   javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:242)
>   at
>   javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:236)
>   at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6297) at
>   javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3275) at
>   java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6062) at
>   java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2039) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4660) at
>   java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2097) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488) at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4575)
>   at
>   java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4236)
>   at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4166)
>   at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2083) at
>   java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2489) at
>   java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4488) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:668) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:81) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:627) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:625) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
>   at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:98)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:641) at
>   java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:639) at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at
>   java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
>   at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:638) at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:269)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:184)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:174)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:169)
>   at
>   java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:161)
>   at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

here's where he get's the exception:

```
Viewport viewport = new Viewport(context.getLayerViewPanel());
Paint fillPaint = null;
Color color = Color.yellow;
Stroke stroke =new BasicStroke(5, BasicStroke.CAP_ROUND,BasicStroke.JOIN_ROUND);
final Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) context.getLayerViewPanel().getGraphics();
```

//in this line:

```
paintGeometryCollection((GeometryCollection) selectedFeatures(),
                                        graphics, viewport, true,
                                        stroke,fillPaint, true,
                                        stroke, color);
```

and here's the other methods that it needs:

```
public Collection selectedFeatures() {
    ArrayList selectedFeatures = new ArrayList();
    for(BasicFeature basicFeature : TitreList) {
    selectedFeatures.add(search().getGeometry());
    // search() is a BasicFeature
    }
    return selectedFeatures;
}   


    private static void paintGeometryCollection(GeometryCollection collection,
        Graphics2D g, Viewport viewport, boolean renderingFill,
        Stroke fillStroke, Paint fillPaint, boolean renderingLine,
        Stroke lineStroke, Color lineColor)
        throws NoninvertibleTransformException {
        //For GeometryCollections, render each element separately. Otherwise,
        //for example, if you pass in a GeometryCollection containing a ring and a
        // disk, you cannot render them as such: if you use Graphics.fill, you'll get
        //two disks, and if you use Graphics.draw, you'll get two rings. [Jon Aquino]
        for (int i = 0; i < collection.getNumGeometries(); i++) {
            paint(collection.getGeometryN(i), g, viewport, renderingFill,
                fillStroke, fillPaint, renderingLine, lineStroke, lineColor);
        }
    }


public static void paint(Geometry geometry, Graphics2D g,
        Viewport viewport, boolean renderingFill, Stroke fillStroke,
        Paint fillPaint, boolean renderingLine, Stroke lineStroke,
        Color lineColor) throws NoninvertibleTransformException {
        if (geometry instanceof GeometryCollection) {
            paintGeometryCollection((GeometryCollection) geometry, g, viewport,
                renderingFill, fillStroke, fillPaint, renderingLine,
                lineStroke, lineColor);

            return;
        }

        Shape shape = toShape(geometry, viewport);
        if (!(shape instanceof GeneralPath) && renderingFill) {
            g.setStroke(fillStroke);
            g.setPaint(fillPaint);
            g.fill(shape);
        }
        if (renderingLine) {
            g.setStroke(lineStroke);
            g.setColor(lineColor);
            g.draw(shape);
        }
    }

private static Shape toShape(Geometry geometry, Viewport viewport)
throws NoninvertibleTransformException {
//At high magnifications, Java rendering can be sped up by clipping
//the Geometry to only that portion visible inside the viewport.
//Hence the code below. [Jon Aquino]
Envelope bufferedEnvelope = EnvelopeUtil.bufferByFraction(viewport.getEnvelopeInModelCoordinates(),
        0.05);
Geometry actualGeometry = geometry;
Envelope geomEnv = actualGeometry.getEnvelopeInternal();
if (! bufferedEnvelope.contains(geomEnv)) {
  /**
   * MD - letting Java2D do more clipping actually seems to be slower!
   * So don't use following "optimization"
   */
  //if (isRatioLarge(bufferedEnvelope, geomEnv, 2)) {
    if (!((geometry instanceof LineString) || (geometry instanceof MultiLineString)))
        actualGeometry = clipGeometry(geometry, bufferedEnvelope);
    //System.out.println("cl");
  //}
}
return viewport.getJava2DConverter().toShape(actualGeometry);
   }

private static Geometry clipGeometry(Geometry geom, Envelope env)
{
  try {
      Geometry clipGeom = EnvelopeUtil.toGeometry(env)
                                   .intersection(geom);
      return clipGeom;
  } catch (Exception e) {
      //Can get a TopologyException if the Geometry is invalid. Eat it. [Jon Aquino]
      //Can get an AssertionFailedException (unable to assign hole to a shell)
      //at high magnifications. Eat it. [Jon Aquino]

      //Alvaro Zabala reports that we can get here with an
      //IllegalArgumentException (points must form a closed linestring)
      //for bad geometries. Eat it. [Jon Aquino]
  }
  return geom;
}
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, use  JLayer(Java7) for painting instead of JViewport, otherwise have to override setScrollMode(JViewport.Xxx) and to use with own RepaintManager (sure those methods aren't something with code snipped posted here)

Comment: to use `Whatever.getGraphics()`; only for printing to the `BufferedImage`, `File`, printing to the `paper printer`, this methods creates internal snapshot that will expire on first event

Comment: not answerable this question without posting an SSCCE, short, runnable, compilable

Comment: @mKorbel oki, but what's the difference between the two? (Jlayer and JViewport). because now am working on Code source of OpenJump, they are using JViewport.

Comment: jump from last millennium to the current :-)

Comment: The stacktrace shows that the problem is in some `ActionListener` defined in SearchPropertiesPlugin.java around line 205, so NOT in your painting code.

Comment: yes it happens in the line i've written above : paintGeometryCollection((GeometryCollection) selectedFeatures(),
                                        graphics, viewport, true,
                                        stroke,fillPaint, true,
                                        stroke, color);

Answer (score 2):

The `public Collection selectedFeatures()` returns `Colecction` but you cast it to `GeometryCollection`. For me that's the problem.

The line `paintGeometryCollection((GeometryCollection) selectedFeatures(),`

Comment: yes that's the problem, but i don't know how to fix it, i just tried with another function that returns geometryCollection : public GeometryCollection selectedGeometry() {
  
   GeometryCollection geometry;
   geometry = (GeometryCollection) search().getGeometry();
   return geometry;
  
    }  but it doesn't work neither

Comment: In fact there are 2 classes GeometryCollection and Collection and they are different. you should get Geometry and transform somehow to GeometryCollection. The GeometryCollection is not standard class so we don't know how to do this. You must do the transfromation.

Comment: yes but i don't know how to transform geometry to geometryCollection. the cast doesn't work :s